# tkinter frame border not displaying

Tags: python, tkinter

I wish to display the border of a frame holding several widgets, but despite setting a width to the border and SUNKEN value to relief, no border shows up

It works perfectly fine on an empty frame so I'm guessing it does not work with a frame with children, is this correct ?

How can I do it anyway ? Or at least introduce separation between two areas of my interface

Test code :

```
import tkinter as Tk

class Application(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #Create window
        self.root = Tk.Tk()

        #Init master frame
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self,self.root,width=640, height=480)
        self.grid()

        #Frame
        self.frame_com_ports = COM_Frame(self,borderwidth=5,relief=Tk.GROOVE)
        self.frame_com_ports.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')

        #Some other frames here...

class COM_Frame(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, **kwargs):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        #Widgets
        self.txt_ports = Tk.Label(self,text="WIDGET1")
        self.txt_ports.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW',pady=3,padx=3)

        self.txt_ports = Tk.Label(self,text="WIDGET2")
        self.txt_ports.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='EW',pady=3,padx=3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Frame borders don't rely on the presence or absence of children. You should be able to see it in all cases. Please provide some actual code that replicates your problem. We can't fix your code if we can't see your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, edited just now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing borderwidth and relief to the COM_Frame constructor, but you aren't using those values when calling the Frame constructor. You need to change this:

```
Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
```

... to this:

```
Tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 5):

The default relief for a frame is tk.FLAT, which means the frame will blend in with its surroundings. To put a border around a frame, set its borderwidth to a positive value and set its relief to one of the standard relief types.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_frame.config(bd=1, relief=tkinter.SOLID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
show_table = tk.Frame(window, width=960, highlightbackground="yellow", highlightthickness=5, height=250, bg="red")
show_table.place(x=5, y=5)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.